# JavaScript reserved word: "preset"

Tags: javascript

I have a form with a select dropdown, and my select tag looks like this:

`<select name='preset' onchange='preset(this);'>`

Right now I have my JavaScript function just do `alert('test');`. Well, when I change my selection in the dropdown, I'm getting an error saying "preset is not a function".  Yes, I verified that it's spelled right, and I even did a generic call to it on page load and got my alert.

If I change my function name to something else, like `presetx` it works just fine.  So I thought maybe "preset" was some kind of reserved word in JavaScript, but I can't seem to find anything saying as such. Why would this happen?

**Update**

Currently I don't have anything else on my test page except for my form and the function.  No framework includes or other code, so I know it's not anything like that.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Some browsers map elements with `name` attributes to global variables.  So `<select name='preset' onchange='preset(this);'>` actually creates (in some browsers) a global property `preset`.  This overwrites the `preset` function.

Since `preset` is now an HTMLSelectElement object, not a function, you get a "not a function" error.

Comment: aaah that makes sense, how could I have missed that :/

Comment: Because it's a moronic anti-feature that should never have existed and should never have been imported into a W3C standard. But I digress...

Comment: Yikes, I never knew about this.  Javascript's very own `register_globals` (though somewhat less dangerous than PHP's)